# write() writes null characters in a file instead of my string

Tags: c, string

When I run my program:

```
char stringnums[(NUMSIZE + 1) * NUMINROW + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMINROW; i++)
        sprintf(stringnums, "%d %s", rand() % (NUMSIZE * 10), stringnums);
    
    if (write(desc, stringnums, strlen(stringnums)) == -1)
        perror("write");
```

I can see some rubbish in the end of a file:

21 21 21 27 22 22 12 12 12 12 ... strange symbols...

Full code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMINROW 10
#define NUMSIZE 3

int main(){
    int desc;
    struct flock fl;
    char stringnums[(NUMSIZE + 1) * NUMINROW + 1];
    char* path = "randnums.txt";
    srand(time(NULL));

    desc = open(path, O_WRONLY);
    if (desc == -1)
        perror("open");

    if (fcntl(desc, F_GETLK, &fl) == -1)
        perror("fcntl_getlk");

    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    if (fcntl(desc, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1)
        perror("fcntl_setlk");

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMINROW; i++)
        sprintf(stringnums, "%d %s", rand() % (NUMSIZE * 10), stringnums);
    
    if (write(desc, stringnums, strlen(stringnums)) == -1)
        perror("write");  

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    if (fcntl(desc, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1)
        perror("fcntl_setlk");

    if (close(desc) == -1)
        perror("close");

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried either to initialize stringnums as "\0" and put in write() sizeof() instead of strlen(), but it's not worked.

Comment: The macros are for changing a size of numbers that will appear in the string and how many numbers will be in one row.

Comment: But why continue performing operations on an invalid file descriptor if ```open``` failed, instead of exiting?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < NUMINROW; i++) sprintf(stringnums, "%d %s", rand() % (NUMSIZE * 10), stringnums);` Are you sure this is really what you want to do?

Comment: In the line `sprintf(stringnums, "%d %s", rand() % (NUMSIZE * 10), stringnums);`, you are copying a string into itself, i.e. you are reading from and writing to the same string at the same time. This is not allowed. It will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Here is the prototype: `int sprintf(char * restrict s,
const char * restrict format, ...);` Take some time to figure out what the `restrict` part means....

Comment: And are there other ways to make a string of random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AndreasWenzel points out, you are attempting to concatenate a string overtop of itself... This is likely to break.

The receiving buffer must be large enough to hold what you want to put into it. Don't scrimp! Why not use 10Kb instead of trying to work with what you hope to be the minimum required?

To correctly concatenate into a large enough buffer:

```
char buf[ 10 * 1024 ], *at = buf;
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    at += sprintf( at, "Something %d ", i );
```

The current length of the growng buffer can be quickly determined by `at - buf`.

You may also want to use `snprintf()` to *pre-calculate* the intending addition to the growing string to avoid writing beyond the end of the buffer.